# Converting foreach to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Current Code:

For each element in the `MapEntryTable`, check the properties `IsDisplayedColumn` and `IsReturnColumn` and if they are true then add the element to another set of lists, its running time would be `O(n)`, there would be many elements with both properties as false, so will not get added to any of the lists in the loop.

```
 foreach (var mapEntry in MapEntryTable)
 {
   if (mapEntry.IsDisplayedColumn)
      Type1.DisplayColumnId.Add(mapEntry.OutputColumnId);

   if (mapEntry.IsReturnColumn)
      Type1.ReturnColumnId.Add(mapEntry.OutputColumnId);
 }
```

Following is the Linq version of doing the same:

```
MapEntryTable.Where(x => x.IsDisplayedColumn == true).ToList().ForEach(mapEntry => Type1.DisplayColumnId.Add(mapEntry.OutputColumnId));       

MapEntryTable.Where(x => x.IsReturnColumn == true).ToList().ForEach(mapEntry => Type1.ReturnColumnId.Add(mapEntry.OutputColumnId));
```

I am converting all such foreach code to linq, as I am learning it, but my question is:

- Do I get any advantage of Linq conversion in this case or is it a disadvantage ?
- Is there a better way to do the same using Linq

UPDATE:

Consider the condition where out of 1000 elements in the list 80% have both properties false, then does where provides me a benefit of quickly finding elements with a given condition.

`Type1` is a custom type with set of `List<int>` structures, `DisplayColumnId` and `ReturnColumnId`

Comment: If you want to shorten your code a little get rid of  "== true" comparision. x => x.IsDisplayedColumn will return true if IsDisplayedColumn is true, no need to compare it against actual value. You are probably also calling ToList() unnecessarily.

Comment: @Andrew B first part is correct, but second is mandatory, Foreach is a List extension method not IEnumerable

Comment: What types are list1 and list2?

Comment: @Mrinal Kamboj That's why I wrote "probably", can't see types of list1 and list2 in your source code ^^.

Comment: @Stephen Kennedy List<int>

Comment: I've never seen a List<int> with a DisplayColumnId property... I must be missing something here. Anyhow, without enough info to answer: you probably don't need `ToList().ForEach()` when you can assign or append a sequence to a list using `sequence.ToList()` or `list.AddRange(sequence)`.

Comment: My mistake, DisplayColumnId and ReturnColumnId are the List<int>, list1 and list2 are the custom types containing List<int>

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Then your names are all very misleading.  You shouldn't have variables called `list1` and `list2` when they aren't lists, and the name `DisplayColumnId` doesn't sound at all like it should be a collection, it's name implies that it's a singular identifier.

Comment: @Servy these  are not the real names, was attempting simple names for the question, but made the blunder, edited

Comment: I've knocked up my comment into an answer, but for simplicity's sake I've assumed list1 to actually be a List<int>. Obviously you'd reference the property which actually holds the list instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ForEach` ins't a LINQ method.  It's a method of `List`.  And not only is it not a part of LINQ, it's *very much* against the very values and patterns of LINQ.  Eric Lippet [explains this in a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) that was written when he was a principle developer on the C# compiler team.

Your "LINQ" approach also:

- Completely unnecessarily copies all of the items to be added into a list, which is both wasteful in time and memory and also conflicts with LINQ's goals of deferred execution when executing queries.
- *Isn't actually a query* with the exception of the `Where` operator.  You're acting on the items in the query, rather than performing a query.  LINQ is a *querying* tool, not a tool for manipulating data sets.
- You're iterating the source sequence twice.  This may or may not be a problem, depending on what the source sequence actually is and what the costs of iterating it are.

A solution that uses LINQ as much as is it is designed for would be to use it like so:

```
foreach (var mapEntry in MapEntryTable.Where(entry => mapEntry.IsDisplayedColumn))
    list1.DisplayColumnId.Add(mapEntry.OutputColumnId);
foreach (var mapEntry in MapEntryTable.Where(entry => mapEntry.IsReturnColumn))
    list2.ReturnColumnId.Add(mapEntry.OutputColumnId);
```

Comment: Why do you need the foreach? you can do something like Andrew suggested:

`list1.DisplayColumnId = MapEntryTable.Where(x => x.IsDisplayedColumn).Select(mapEntry => mapEntry.OutputColumnId);`

`list2.ReturnColumnId = MapEntryTable.Where(x => x.IsReturnColumn).Select(mapEntry => mapEntry.OutputColumnId);`

Comment: @Carlos That's assuming the type of `list2.ReturnColumnId` is `IEnumerable`, and that all of the content there should be replaced with this content.  If that's not the type of the variable, and/or there are items in that collection that should also stay there, then that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the elaborate point, I will stick with foreach, but does the Where extension method in linq does a quick search of elements or it enumerates through complete list and thus would not yield any major benefit of filtering, so my original code would be best

Comment: @MrinalKamboj In this context the difference between the two is very minor, and pretty much entirely stylistic.  Your original code is just fine.  In other situations where you have a more complex query to execute LINQ can have more notable advantages.

Comment: i revised my code to use `AddRange` now, which takes an `IEnumerable`, and doesn't mess with existing content.

Answer (score 1):

I would say stick with the original way with the `foreach` loop, since you are only iterating through the list 1 time over.

also your linq should look more like this:

```
list1.DisplayColumnId.AddRange(MapEntryTable.Where(x => x.IsDisplayedColumn).Select(mapEntry => mapEntry.OutputColumnId));       

list2.ReturnColumnId.AddRange(MapEntryTable.Where(x => x.IsReturnColumn).Select(mapEntry => mapEntry.OutputColumnId));
```

Comment: I doubt that would work since `Select` would return an `IEnumerable<T>` and `list1.DisplayColumnId` is most likely a `List<T>`, but even if you slapped a `ToList()` to the end the results would be different from adding to existing collections (basically you'd lose any data that was already in the collection).

Comment: Agreed with @ juharr this will not work for me, I will lose the existing list data, they are not empty collections

Answer (score 1):

The performance of foreach vs Linq ForEach are almost exactly the same, within nano seconds of each other.  Assuming you have the same internal logic in the loop in both versions when testing.

However a for loop, outperforms both by a LARGE margin.  for(int i; i < count; ++i) is much faster than both.  Because a for loop doesn't rely on an IEnumerable implementation (overhead).  The for loop compiles to x86 register index/jump code.  It maintains an incrementor, and then it's up to you to retrieve the item by it's index in the loop.

Using a Linq ForEach loop though does have a big disadvantage.  You cannot break out of the loop.  If you need to do that you have to maintain a boolean like "breakLoop = false", set it to true, and have each recursive exit if breakLoop is true... Bad performing there.  Secondly you cannot use continue, instead you use "return".

I never use Linq's foreach loop.

If you are dealing with linq, e.g.

```
List<Thing> things = .....;
var oldThings = things.Where(p.DateTime.Year < DateTime.Now.Year);
```

That internally will foreach with linq and give you back only the items with a year less than the current year.  Cool..

But if I am doing this:

```
List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();

foreach(XElement node in Results) {
    things.Add(new Thing(node));
}
```

I don't need to use a linq for each loop.  Even if I did...

```
foreach(var node in thingNodes.Where(p => p.NodeType == "Thing") {
    if (node.Ignore) {
        continue;
    }
    thing.Add(node);
}
```

even though I could write that cleaner like

```
foreach(var node in thingNodes.Where(p => p.NodeType == "Thing" && !node.Ignore) {
    thing.Add(node);
}
```

There is no real reason I can think of to do this..>

```
   things.ForEach(thing => {
       //do something
       //can't break
       //can't continue
       return; //<- continue
   });
```

And if I want the fastest loop possible,

```
for (int i = 0; i < things.Count; ++i) {
    var thing = things[i];
    //do something
}
```

Will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your LINQ isn't quite right as you're converting the results of `Where` to a List and then pseudo-iterating over those results with `ForEach` to add to another list. Use `ToList` or `AddRange` for converting or adding sequences to lists.

Example, where overwriting `list1` (if it were actually a `List<T>`):

```
list1 = MapEntryTable.Where(x => x.IsDisplayedColumn == true)
.Select(mapEntry => mapEntry.OutputColumnId).ToList();
```

or to append:

```
list1.AddRange(MapEntryTable.Where(x => x.IsDisplayedColumn == true)
.Select(mapEntry => mapEntry.OutputColumnId));
```

Comment: thanks second part would be beneficial, as I need to add to an existing collection

Answer (score 0):

In C#, to do what you want functionally in one call, you have to write your own partition method. If you are open to using F#, you can use `List.Partition<'T>`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353782.aspx

Comment: In that case, you have to create a function that takes in your source list and a lambda expression, and then return a `Tuple<List<MapEntry>, List<MapEntry>>` after applying the lambda expression to your source.

Comment: Which, incidentally, would be easiest implemented with your foreach code above, or would require a call to GroupBy.